# How to add three figures in latex (two in first row and one below) like this?

Tags: subfloats

How to add three figures in latex (two in first row and one below) like this?

```
(a)  (b)   % // (a) and (b) should be in the first row.
(c)
```

I want that manuscript text should appear on the right side of figure (c).

Comment: Some more details like a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) would be helpful. In my answer I didn't notice your comment that "manuscript text should appear on the right side of figure (c)". Please add an example/better explanation as to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        & \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-c} &
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot...btw i am using IEEEtran class. Will it work??

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi Yes, it should. There are just basic latex commands. Btw, the traditional way to "thank" is by up-voting and assigning a tick, if appropriate.

Comment: I did'nt know...the traditional way....new to stackexchange...i've done that...